# Architecture for image storage and retrieval system

Tags: api, rest, architecture, connection, integration

What is best architecture to store images for blog and retrieval? I have a usecase where I have to design image storage / retrieval system for articles. Where and how should I store store these images and retrieve / access those while displaying contents of article with minimum latency?

It would be great if you can provide any reference for this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want minimum latency for image retrieval, you need to use a CDN (Content Delivery Network)

Check out [this article](https://uploadcare.com/blog/cdn-for-images/) for more details.

For example, AWS offers [Cloud Front](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Introduction.html) which is very simple to use - store the images into an S3 bucket, and then use dedicated CloudFront URLs on your client-side code, to fetch the images.

There are other CDN providers out there, you can find them right away on a Google search.